# Thinking like in ancient Greece

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-history

The next result is attributed to Archimedes: The equation $x^3-ax^2+(4/9)a^2b$ has a positive root if and only if $a>3b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers.

This problem appeared in the book The Heritage of Thales by W.S. Anglin and J. Lambek. The idea was proved with the tools of the time.

I tried to interpret the equivalent equation $\Big(\frac{2a}{3x}\Big)^2=\frac{a-x}{b}$ to show through proportions what you want: area, segments, etc. But I can not find a way to solve it. Is it the way to proceed? Any suggestions?

P.S.: Sorry for my English, I'm not native. :v

Comment: Archimedes did not know variables or real numbers, and he would not have said something is positive since he did not know negative numbers. God knows what Anglin and Lambek were thinking. I wouldn't be surprised if the cubic had something to do with his solution of the problem of trisecting the angle.